# Collectionview cell to open new view

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, viewcontroller

I have a collection view with 6 cells in it how do I have each cell open a new viewcontroller when clicked?

Comment: 2 questions to clarify: Do your 6 cells use an identical layout? Or is each different? And should a tap on a cell open the same view controller as any other cell, but showing different content (like tapping a thumbnail, leading to the big picture)? Or should each cell lead to a different view controller (like a settings overview leading to different setting panels)?

Comment: The 6 cells use the same layout, and a tap should bring up a different view for each cell tapped. I know you can do it in a single view with different content, but for me, as a beginner, i think using multiple views is the way to go, for now :)

Comment: can't seem to put in my code for u to see?

Comment: (Meta) You should be able to edit your original question and paste in your code. Just make sure to select the code in the text field and click the code button above the text field (the two curly brackets "{}").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve your goal you need to edit 2 files:

1. **In the Storyboard** you need to add a cell view for each static cell in your *Collection View*. Just drag as many `UICollectionViewCells` onto the *Collection View*. For each cell you need to define a unique reusable identifier (meaning a name like *CellType1*) in the *Attributes Inspector* when a cell is selected in the Storyboard's Document Outline. And then control-drag from each cell to the desired target view controller to create a `Push segue` (provided that your collection view is associated with a `UINavigationController`).
2. **Create a subclass of `UICollectionViewController`** and assign it in the Storyboard's as the *Collection View Controller*'s class (see the *Identity Inspector*).

In your `UICollectionViewController` subclass implement the following methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
  return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  // Enter the number of static cells that are present in the Storyboard's collection view:
  return 3;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  // Enter the reusable identifiers that are defined for each cell in the Storyboard's collection view:
  NSArray *cellIdentifiers = @[@"CellType1", @"CellType2", @"CellType3"];
  NSInteger cellIdentifierIndex = indexPath.item;

  // Make one identifier the default cell for edge cases (we use CellType1 here):
  if (cellIdentifierIndex >= cellIdentifiers.count) cellIdentifierIndex = 0;

  UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifiers[cellIdentifierIndex] forIndexPath:indexPath];
  // Configure the cell …
  return cell;
}
```

I've created a demo app to show a full implementation: https://github.com/widescape/StaticCollectionViewCells

Comment: You're welcome! :) Please make sure to mark my answer as accepted if it answered your question.